# python : imported packages with 'nested' modules

Tags: python, import, module, nested, package

When i import modules , this nested scenario works fine. But when i try to import packages , i got inconsistent result. Here's the very simple case :

contents of my current folder :

```
mypackages <directory>
   __init__.py 
   one.py
   two.py
   three.py
```

this is the script :

```
__init__.py :
import one

one.py :
import two

two.py :
import three
```

I'm expecting that i should be able to access **two** and **three** this way :

```
import mypackages
mypackages.one.two
mypackages.one.two.three
```

or in other word the logical level shoul be like this :

```
one
  two
    three
```

But when i do **import mypackages**, i got all the modules exposed at the same level :

```
>>> import mypackages
>>> print dir(mypackages)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 
'__path__', 'one', 'three', 'two']
```

It should only show  `one` module , right ?
I'm confused why it shows all `one , two` and `three` which means they are at the same level ( i can use **mypackages.two** and **mypackages.three** directly ).

Does anyone have any explaination ?

Answer (score 13):

You should read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).

By putting the files at the same level, you put them is the same package level.
In your case, you need to get this architecture:

```
mypackage
├── __init__.py
├── one.py  # contains "import two"
└── two
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── two.py  # contains "import three"
    └── three
        ├── __init__.py
        └── three.py
```

And then, you can access the package with:

```
import mypackage.one
import mypackage.one.two
import mypackage.one.two.three
```

Comment: Care to expand this to cover the usage of functions and classes from the subpackages?

Comment: You mean, how to access members of the module objects ?

Comment: Yes. I tried the suggested solution, but couldn't make it work. In a dir, I have a folder `intl` which contains a file (`scanner.py`), and wanted to turn it into a package. In the main file, doing `import intl` and `scanner = intl.Scanner()` didn't work. I had to modify `__init__.py` and add `from .scanner import Scanner` in it... So, a use case for using a function and a class from packages/subpackages would improve this answer, because it doesn't mention anything about modifying the `__init__.py`. While I managed to get my script to work, I don't know if I took the right approach :)